# SSRS data driven subscription

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have created a data driven subscription for an SSRS report where I have written the dataset query to fetch the report parameters. Now, whatever email id I provide gets all the reports generated by passing different parameters.
Here, I want to achieve is sending the report generated by a particular parameter to a particular email id. For all the different parameters, the reports generated should be delivered to different email ids.
Please help me if this is achievable in SSRS and how to achieve this?
Your help will be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have enterprise edition?

Comment: Yes, I am having enterprise edition and those all things are not a problem. I just want to know how to do it.

Comment: Use a data-driven subscription.

Comment: Please anyone provide any insight here as i really want to do this.

Comment: What's wrong with using a data-driven subscription?

Comment: I am already using the data driven subscription...however i want to send the report generated by passing different parameters to different email id.

Comment: lets say for parameter 1 the generated report should go to email id 1 and for parameter 2 to email id 2. All this i  want in one subscription. I hope it clarifies the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround and got the solution. I created a new table having two columns, one column with all the parameters and the next column with the corresponding email id. In the dataset query I wrote the select statement by inner joining the two tables. So, this way I achieved the required dataset and using that got me the required data driven subscription.
Thanks everyone for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your subscription, check the "data driven subscription" radio box. This will display a "Dataset" heading with "Edit Dataset" button. Press that button and an empty text box will open. Paste your query in here and press validate. If the query validates, press apply. If it doesn't, it means there is an error in the query.

Now in your dataset you will see your fields. Sometimes these will be formatted with xml. Go down to your delivery and in the email field you can select "Get value from dataset". Next to it pick the email field from your query. (If you have the xml field this might be hard to decipher... if you have dual screens put it on the left screen and mouse over for the full value)

For your parameters you can do the same theing with the "Get value from dataset" option.

That's subscriptions via dataset in a nutshell.

Comment: Thank you lucky....I understand this part and even though i get the email id and parameters from the dataset, how can i make sure that for a particular parameter it sends report to a particular email id. Please reply on this.

Comment: It will select the parameter in the same row as the email address.

Answer (score 0):

As a standard variant of Mrityunjay Kumar's answer you may press EditDataSet on SubscriptionPage
and may select  field#1 as the input parameter of the report
and may select field#2 as the email to send.
After that you may choose field#1 in DeliveryOption
and field#2 in ReportParameter on the same SubscriptionPage.
So sending reports will be depends on email in field#1 and parameter in field#2.